# C# Thermal Printer Doesn't Print Arabic Characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print Arabic character using my Thermal Printer, I've tried lots of solution but nothing so far worked to me.

so I have this line which is print the string:

```
string ArabicChars = "اللغة العربية";
e.PrintLine(ArabicChars);
```

When Printer Prints, It's Print characters not readable and symbols.

Can someone help me how I can fix that?

Printer Model: **BTP-R880NPII**

**Library I use to print to Thermal Printer: [ESCPOS_NET](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET)**

Please note that I've tried to print on the printer using Notepad and it's printing Arabic, But from C# It's printing like Unicode symbols

Comment: What printer model are you using?

Comment: BTP-R880NPII ..@Simon

Comment: Does that printer have a font available that supports Arabic?

Comment: @KenWhite I checked the printer properties and font section, I have there English and Windows Language and Chinese Language to select btw them

Comment: Actually I think that I need to convert the string I'm trying to print, but I have no idea how to do that programmatically

Comment: Did you try writing to a console in arabic from c#?

Comment: Can you print Arabic characters on that printer from something like Word?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes i can print from notepad and word Arabic texts

Comment: Try this line:

string ArabicChars = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("اللغة العربية")));

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, instead of just two lines out of any context?

Comment: @Simon This is what it's printed: 'DD:) 'D91(J)

Comment: @KenWhite I can Provide, but the rest code is English characters to print the same.. So i think it's not a good idea to repeat the code here.. But I'm using to print a library called ESCPOS_NET

Comment: https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET/issues/88

Answer (score 2):

> Yes i can print from notepad and word Arabic texts

> I'm using to print a library called ESCPOS_NET

Well there's your problem, ditch your broken library. If Notepad and Word can print, then your printer has a regular old Windows driver, and you can use the normal .Net printing API: [`System.Drawing.Printing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Actually this worked for me, can you help me to set the arabic encoding here: 
string text = "中文菜单";
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("GB18030");
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        string isoString = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes);

        var e = new EPSON();
        printer.Write(ByteSplicer.Combine(
            e.Initialize(),
            //e.CodePage(CodePage.CHINA),
            e.PrintLine(isoString),
            e.FullCut()
        ));

Comment: Yes, you said your printer only has built-in fonts for English and Chinese. So why do you keep banging your head on this the wrong way? Use your printer driver to feed it your OS's fonts, like a normal human being.

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines:

```
string ArabicChars = "اللغة العربية"; 
var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256); 
var bytes = arabic.GetBytes(ArabicChars); 
e.PrintLine(arabic.GetString(bytes));
```

Comment: Not works actually... still printing the same